# Incomplete localization of `{{ entry.postDate.diff(now)|duration }}`

Tags: localization, bug

In a Dutch site, when I output `{{ entry.postDate.diff(now)|duration }}`, the result is something like `5 dagen, 3 uren, 43 minuten, and 42 seconden`. Why is the English "and" not localized? My understanding (I don't speak Dutch) is that "and" should be "en" in Dutch...

Am I missing some crucial step here? Thanks!